# Duplicated column name with sequelize.where

Tags: sequelize.js

## What you are doing?

I'm trying to use a function with `sequelize.where` inside a included model

### Post a minimal code sample that reproduces the issue, including models and associations

```js
class Promotion extends SZ.Model {}

Promotion.init({
    id: {
        type: SZ.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    id_promotion_type: { 
        type: SZ.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    name: SZ.STRING,
}, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'promotions',
    modelName: 'promotion',
})



class PromotionType extends SZ.Model {}

PromotionType.init({
    id: {
        type: SZ.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: SZ.STRING
}, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'promotion_types',
    modelName: 'promotion_type',
})



Promotion.belongsTo(PromotionType, { foreignKey: 'id_promotion_type' })

Promotion.findAll({
    include: { 
        model: PromotionType,
        where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('unaccent_string', sequelize.col('name')), 'ilike', '%à%'),
    }
})
.then(result => console.log(result))
```

### What do you expect to happen?

The query builder should recognize that the name column I'm refering to is the one from the PromotionType model, something like `"promotion_type"."name"`

### What is actually happening?

I'm getting an error because name exists in both tables

```js
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: reference to column "name" is ambiguous
```

Query being generated:

```sql
SELECT "promotion"."id", 
"promotion"."id_promotion_type", 
"promotion"."name", 
"promotion"."createdAt",
"promotion"."updatedAt",
"promotion_type"."id" AS "promotion_type.id", 
"promotion_type"."name" AS "promotion_type.name", 
"promotion_type"."createdAt" AS "promotion_type.createdAt",
"promotion_type"."updatedAt" AS "promotion_type.updatedAt" 
FROM "promotions" AS "promotion" 
INNER JOIN "promotion_types" AS "promotion_type" 
ON "promotion"."id_promotion_type" = "promotion_type"."id" 
AND unaccent_string("name") ilike '%à%';
```

Do you guys have any workaroud for it?
Thanks for you attention..

Answer (score 1):

Add the table name in the where clause `sequelize.col('promotion_type.name')`

Comment: This is my current solution, but it needs to be generic, since sequelize creates aliases for tables. In a deeper include nesting it may look like ```"promotion_type->User.House->Address"."name"````. It'll be troublesome to manage this.